# Regex Visual Basic UDF not executing as expected

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I am busy with a regular expression for VB and I cant seem to find where I am going wrong here.

Example:

Pattern:(?<=\d{10,11})(.|[\r\n])*(?=Mobile)

Input: 6578543567 ***Text I want to retain*** Mobile Operation

Output: #Name?

- List item

The number consists of 10 and 11 digit telephone numbers.
The text I want to retain varies in length.
The text always precedes the word Mobile.

```
Function regex(strInput As String, matchPattern As String, Optional ByVal outputPattern As String = "$0") As Variant
Dim inputRegexObj As New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp, outputRegexObj As New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp, outReplaceRegexObj As New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp
Dim inputMatches As Object, replaceMatches As Object, replaceMatch As Object
Dim replaceNumber As Integer

With inputRegexObj
    .Global = True
    .MultiLine = True
    .IgnoreCase = False
    .Pattern = matchPattern
End With
With outputRegexObj
    .Global = True
    .MultiLine = True
    .IgnoreCase = False
    .Pattern = "\$(\d+)"
End With
With outReplaceRegexObj
    .Global = True
    .MultiLine = True
    .IgnoreCase = False
End With

Set inputMatches = inputRegexObj.Execute(strInput)
If inputMatches.count = 0 Then
    regex = False
Else
    Set replaceMatches = outputRegexObj.Execute(outputPattern)
    For Each replaceMatch In replaceMatches
        replaceNumber = replaceMatch.SubMatches(0)
        outReplaceRegexObj.Pattern = "\$" & replaceNumber

        If replaceNumber = 0 Then
            outputPattern = outReplaceRegexObj.Replace(outputPattern, inputMatches(0).Value)
        Else
            If replaceNumber > inputMatches(0).SubMatches.count Then
                'regex = "A to high $ tag found. Largest allowed is $" & inputMatches(0).SubMatches.Count & "."
                regex = CVErr(xlErrValue)
                Exit Function
            Else
                outputPattern = outReplaceRegexObj.Replace(outputPattern, inputMatches(0).SubMatches(replaceNumber - 1))
            End If
        End If
    Next
    regex = outputPattern
End If
End Function
```

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/491907/extracting-data-between-two-characters-in-excel

Answer (score 1):

IIRC, VBA doesn't support lookarounds in it's Regular Expression implementation.

But, this appears to be a relatively easy string to match. You have a group of consecutive numbers, followed by a space, and then you want to match an undisclosed amount of words up to the word "Mobile".

You could use the following pattern to accomplish this:

```
\d+\s(.*?)\sMobile
```

Details <sup>*[(See it in action here)](https://regex101.com/r/JmZHxp/1)*</sup>:

- `\d` any digit

  - `+` <sub>*(Quantifier)*</sub> One to unlimited times - greedy
- `\s` a single whitespace character
- `(...)` capturing group to grab the text you want to return
- `.` any character

  - `*?` <sub>*(Quantifier)*</sub> Zero to unlimited times - lazy
- `\s` a single whitespace character
- `Mobile` literally matches the word Mobile

### What's with the greedy vs lazy quantifiers?

The first quantifier `+` is **Greedy**. What makes this greedy? The lack of the `?` immediately following this quantifier makes it greedy. What this essentially does is it will consume as *much ass it possibly can* of the `\d`.

Since we added a `\s` to the end of that statement, this won't really change the outcome because it will have to match all the digits anyway to get to that space `\s`. However, if you decided you wanted to capture `(...)` the space and you removed the `\s`, then this would be important - because your `.*?` will consume all but one of your numbers `\d` if this was lazy.

*So, then why are we using a lazy quantifier with `.*?`?* Well, if your input string contained two words that said **Mobile**, a greedy quantifier would *consumer* the first word and match up **up to** the second. If you only want to match up to the first word of **Mobile**, then you want to make it lazy.

### So Finally - Now how do I *retrieve* the text in my capturing group `(...)`?

With VBA, you would use the `Matches` object. First I would recommend testing to ensure that there is a match - this can be done in a simple `If...Then` statement. Once this test passes, you can then safely obtain your return value.

```
With New RegExp
    .Pattern = "\d+\s(.*?)\sMobile"
    .IngoreCase = True      'If your 'Mobile' word can be any case, switch to false
    If .Test(inputString) Then
        retVal = .Execute(inputString)(0).SubMatches(0)
    End If
End With
```

- `inputString` would be the string that contains the test values.
- `retVal` would be what is returned from your capturing group.